# Derivation of normal distribution pdf, derivation of the power of the pdf.

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, normal-distribution, density-function

I'm trying to learn to derive the pdf of normal distribution, that is

$$f(x; \mu,\sigma^2)=\dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[−\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{x−\mu}\sigma\right)^2\right]$$

Firstly, there is a hypothesis to derive this pdf, which is the coordinate is farther away from the origin, the lower the value of $f(x)$.

After defining the area and transformation to polar form on the Cartesian plane, I get $f(x)=Ae^{\frac{Cx^2}2}$.

By the hypothesis, the *C* of $f(x)=Ae^{\frac{Cx^2}2}$ will be negative.
So the question is what is the theorem that implies *C* is negative

Comment: If $C$ is not negative then $\int_0^{\infty} e^{Cx^2/2}dx=+\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That the pdf integrates to $1$ instead of $\infty$.